# Using 2 different shared libraries for the same executable

Tags: dynamic-linking, shared-libraries

I need your advise on a project that confuses me a lot.

Imagine that I am compiling a binary, which has to be linked with **two** 3rd party libraries, let's call them libA.so and libB.so.
The problem relies on the fact that these two libraries have been compiled with a different version of the libcrypto.

In my system, I have both libcrypto(s) but can I use it simultaneously?
Is there a way to say *libA.so* use /path/to/libA/needed/libcrypto.so ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Do you get any error message when you try to compile or to run your program?

Comment: No, everything is fine during compilation.
To find the "libcrypto" I used the LD_DEBUG because the failing library (in runtime) was a different one.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can not have 2 versions of a library loaded. Say there is a function `encrypt()` which does different things in the two versions (perhaps there is an old buggy version and a newer fixed version). Which `encrypt()` is going to be used? You can use things like LD_LIBRARY_PATH to add some directories early in the search path to help select which single version of `libcrypto` you would like loaded. e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libA/needed ./myprog`

Comment: Yes, I see your point.
The problem is that I cannot re-compile these libraries. So either LD_PRELOAD or LD_LIBRARY_PATH are not helping me here.
Thanks for your time.